# why my whirlpool refrigerator stops working when the door is opened

Tags: electrical

my whirlpool refrigerator model # GSF26C4EXWO2 stops when my door is opened allso it does not cool I changed the bi metal thermostat,replaced the start switch, compaciter and condenser fan.Could you give me any thought what else to look for.Would the thermister cause the problem

Comment: Can keep spending money replacing parts or start testing to find out what is wrong.  Should be a wiring diagram online.  At least now you have four used parts you can sell.

Comment: Does not cool is a big deal. For many modern fridges it's also the end, as they are not made to be repaired if the cooling circuit fails, and repair cost exceeds replacement generally as a result of that choice in design, unless it's still in warranty. Stops when the door is open might be by design, to limit blowing cold air out - so long as it starts again shortly after the door is closed,  (might have to wait for minimum compressor off time first) that's not a big deal.

Comment: put a pice of tape over the door switch to simulate always closed door, is it now running